# Handle utf 8 characters in unix

Tags: unix, exception, encoding, utf-8

I was trying to find a solution for my problem and after looking at the forums I couldn't so I'll explain my problem here.

We receive a csv file from a client with some special characters and encoded as unknown-8bit. We convert this csv file to xml using an awk script. With the xml file we make an API call to our system using utf-8 as default encoding. The response is an error with following information:

org.apache.xerces.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence

The content of the file is as bellow:

151215901579-109617744500,sandra,sandra,Coesfeld,,Coesfeld,48653,DE,1,2.30,ASTRA 16V CAVALIER CALIBRA TURBO BLUE 10,53.82,GB,,.80,3,ASTRA 16V CAVALIER CALIBRA TURBO BLUE 10MM 4CORE IGNITION HT LEADS WIRES MLR.CR,,sandra@online.de,parcel1,Invalid Request,,%004865315500320004648880276,INTL,%004865315500320004648880276,1,INTL,DPD,180380,INTL,2.30,Send A2B Ltd,4th Floor,200 Gray’s Inn Road,LONDON,,WC1X8XZ,GBR,

I think the problem is in the field "200 Gray’s Inn Road" cause when I use utf-8 encoding it automatically converts "'" character by a x92 value.

Does anybody know how can I handle this?

Thanks in advance,

Sandra

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, don't pretend it's UTF-8 if it isn't. Find out what the encoding is, or replace all non-ASCII characters with the UTF-8 [REPLACEMENT CHARACTER](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0fffd/index.htm) sequence 0xEF 0xBF 0xBD.

Since you are able to view this particular sample just fine, you apparently already know which encoding it is (even if you don't know that you know -- it would be whatever your current set-up is using) -- I would guess [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) which uses 0x92 for a curvy right single quote.

Comment: Hi triplee, Thanks for your response. Because this is not the only file I'm going to receive I need to set a default encoding. We decided to use utf-8 because is the one that covers more characters. The problem is I'm going to have the same problem with more special characters so I need a way to replace all hex character with the each value. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: I don't understand what you want, and it seems like the topic for a separate question anyway. Awk's `gsub` function can probably do what you want easily.

Comment: UTF-8 is a poor choice because it's incompatible with most legacy 8-bit encodings. On the other hand, blindly applying Latin-1 to files which might be in a different coding isn't a good idea, either. You really should figure out the encoding of your input data; that's the only sane solution.

Comment: @tripleee: UTF-8 was designed for compatibility as an 8-Bit extended ASCII encoding. Still, legacy encodings are per definitionem not Unicode, and using the wrong charset is always wrong.

Comment: I mean it's incompatible in the sense that many strings are simply invalid UTF-8 strings so you cannot get away with pretending that the character set doesn't make a difference.  I do agree that that would be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Find out the actual encoding first, best would be asking the sender.
If you cannot do so, and also for sanity-checking, the [unix command `file`](https://superuser.com/a/351658) is very useful for that (the linked page shows more options).
Next step, convert to UTF-8.

As it is obviously an ASCII-based encoding, you could just discard all non-ASCII or replace them on encoding, if that loss is acceptable.

As an alternative, open it in the editor of your choice and flip the encoding used for interpreting the data until you get something useful. My guess is you'll have either Latin-1 or Windows-1252, but check it for yourself.

Last step, do what you wanted to do, in comforting knowledge that you now have valid UTF-8.

Comment: Hi deduplicator, thank you for responding my meesage. I used file command to detect encoding and I'm getting unknown-8bit. If I try to use this encoding for the API call it doesn't work so I decided to set utf-8 as a default encoding. I was trying to avoid discard the characters so it would be great if I could replace them. Any idea?

Comment: Added one more option, which boils down use your built-in advanced pattern recognition machine (aka brain) to do it manually. Not that good, but often better than ust giving up.

Comment: You can use enca or chardet to guess the encoding.